# jQuery .on() versus tying event to selector?

Tags: jquery

I am looking over the docs on this [page](http://api.jquery.com/on/). They have examples like these ...

```
$("p").on("click", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});

$("form").on("submit", false)

$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Why is this better or how is it different than this ...

```
$("p").click(function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});

$("form").submit(false);

$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

As a final question why would you want to do this ...

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

instead of ...

```
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: I tried to answer this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10827586/344304

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: It's not necessarily better, but since the examples are in the `.on` documentation, it makes sense to make us of `.on` there ;)

Comment: one reason can be now, `click` and `submit` uses `$.on` themselves under the hood in jQuery source. So it's good to adopt with it.

Comment: It's interesting to see that so many seem to have this question since the introduction of `.on`. Its primary purpose is to unify the the event handling methods `.bind`, `.live` and `.delegate`. Nothing changed for the shorthand methods. The only difference is that they were using `.bind`, now they are using `.on`. Your question can be answered by any other answer that was given to "What is the difference between `.bind` and `.click`". They are shorthand methods for convenience, you are free to use whatever you prefer.

Comment: @FelixKling that's not entirely true, according to Souflane Hassou's answer.

Comment: @11684: Could please be more specific? What is not true?

Comment: @FelixKling you should read the article linked to by Souflane. It's very interesting!

Comment: @11684: Yeah, I read it, but I don't see how this is relate to my comment or shorthand methods. The article does not even mention them and rightly so: They have nothing to do with the whole `.live`, `.delegate`, `.bind` methods/problematic, they are just convient wrappers for `.bind` (`.on`).  There is no better it's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and links. @felex "there is no better ...". Is there a best practice? What is the preferred way that they should be used from a maintainability point of view and for the programmer that must maintain them when I no longer do? (python guy here, i hate ambiguity when it comes to these things :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Differences Between jQuery .bind() vs .live() vs .delegate() vs .on()](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

The biggest take aways from this article are that...

Using the .bind() method is very costly as it attaches the same event handler to every item matched in your selector.

You should stop using the .live() method as it is deprecated and has a lot of problems with it.

The .delegate() method gives a lot of "bang for your buck" when dealing with performance and reacting to dynamically added elements.

That the new .on() method is mostly syntax sugar that can mimic .bind(), .live(), or .delegate() depending on how you call it.

The new direction is to use the new .on method. Get familiar with the syntax and start using it on all your jQuery 1.7+ projects.

Comment: All the shorthand methods are just syntactic sugar as well. You did not actually explain what the difference is between them and `.on`.

Answer (score 5):

There are few differences when using `.on` instead of specific handler such as `.click` e.t.c.

1. The purpose `.on()` method is to provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers in one syntax. You can write a consistent syntax using `.on` instead of mix of bunch `.on`, `.submit` or `.click`.
2. `.on` supports event delegation but specific handlers (ex: `.click`) does not. Read more under section **Direct and delegated events** from [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
3. Using `.on` you can bind multiple event handler like `.on('click dblclick')`
4. Using .on you can bind namespace events like `.on('click.myClick')`. Read more under section **Event names and namespaces** from [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
5. Internally `.click` triggers `.on` so basically you are avoiding an extra function call. - [.click source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.click)

And now the verdict,

> $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
>       event.preventDefault();
>     });
>
> Why is this better or how is it different than this
>
> $("form").submit(function(event) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>   });

`$("form").on(` is better as for the reason 1 and 5 stated above

Answer (score 3):

The `click`, `submit`, etc methods are simply convenience methods for their respective `on` and `trigger` equivalents.

I would only use them if I believed that they improve the readability of the code. In general however I find the `on` and `trigger` methods  express the intent of the code more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `$.on()`, even when you're not using delegation is good because it introducing a familiar and consistent syntax into your code.
2. Additionally it's used heavily in the jQuery source, meaning you can cut out the middle-man when calling methods like `$.bind()`.
3. Using `$.submit()` or `$.click()` to assign handlers is confusing since it is also used to trigger those events.

Then there's the added benefit of event-delegation, which can save you from adding events to hundreds of elements when it's only necessary to add to one. Suppose you had 100 `<td>` element and you wanted to alert their contents on click. You could do this:

```
$("td").click(function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

But now you've added 100 new event handlers. Really bad for performance. Using `$.on()`, you can bind to just the `<table>`, and examine all events to see what raised them. If it was a `<td>`, you can respond accordingly:

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Voila, only one event has been bound, and only one event handler was introduced into the application. Massive performance increase.

This is one of the biggest reasons why `$.on()` trumps `$.click()` or `$.submit()` any day.